# jquery update by #id but not (this) element

Tags: jquery

i need to hide two buttons after click on first one but I can not to achieve it. The first one will disappier but the second one is still showed. Can somebody advice me how to do it correctly? Thanks

```
<p:outputPanel id="ulozitPristupyBtnWrapper">
        <p:commandButton type="button" id="ulozitPristupyBtn" value="Uložiť prístupy" rendered="#{userControlBean.editAccess}"
            disabled="#{accessTreeBean.readOnlySystems}" styleClass="idm-gap-top" onclick="jQuery(this).parent().hide(); jQuery('#panelGridPotvrdit').hide();"  />
</p:outputPanel>

<p:panelGrid id="panelGridPotvrdit" columns="2" >
        <p:outputLabel for="cisloPoziadavky" value="Zadajte číslo požiadavky(ServiceDesk):" />
        <p:inputText id="cisloPoziadavky" value="#{accessTreeBean.numberOfRequest}" />
        <p:commandButton id="potvrditBtn" action="#{accessTreeBean.onUlozitPristupy}" value="Potvrdiť"  update="#{cc.attrs.update}" styleClass="idm-gap-top"/>
</p:panelGrid>
```

Comment: remove  jQuery(this).parent().hide(); from onclick

Comment: jQuery(this).parent().hide(); is the correct piece of code which works fine :D...this part hides the clicked buttot but the second button is still showed and i need hide it too.

Comment: whats css is there in idm-gap-top class

Comment: there is just some margin

Comment: Please share the rendered html to the browser, my guess is after rendering id of below div is been changed.

Comment: I cant to add picture to this web due to low reputation :/

Comment: jsut wirte click to the browser and see the source code copy and paste it that you can do rigth ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using jquery's fadeIn() and fadeOut():

```
$(".button").on("click", function(){
   $(".button").fadeOut();
   $("#message").fadeIn();
});

$("#reappear").on("click", function(){
   $("#message").fadeOut();
   $(".button").fadeIn();
});
```

A very general fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/f2nww7ns/1/

Comment: Thanks for answer, but i would like to run my code with this functionality as value of onclick attribute. I still cant access correctly id of the second button. My piece of code is encapsulated into tab/tabview/form.